# React native - adb failed to install Exponent-2.6.4.apk

Tags: android, react-native, android-virtual-device

I'm trying React Native for the first time and I'm having trouble running on AVD. On my physical device, after installing expo client app and scanning the QR code, it all works seamlessly. But when I try to run the project on AVD, I will end up with an error `Error running adb: adb: failed to install C:\Users\janam\.expo\android-apk-cache\Exponent-2.6.4.apk:`

I tried install Exponent-2.6.4.apk directly into AVD from Expo.io, but it also ended with the error `"There was a problem parsing the package"`

Any advices..

Answer (score 1):

Delete your emulator, and recreate a new one but before that make sure you select a device that supports the google play store.(You will see a play store logo like this)
[image: Example]

And in SDK manager > SDK platform for whatever version of android your choose make sure you download the following:

- Android SDK platform
- Google API
- Google Play